# How to clear ImageView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

I drew some lines on imageView and I need to clear my screen. How can I clear imageView?

When I was working with CGShapeLayer I was using removeFromSuperlayer. 
Is there any alternative to this function?

```
 weak var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer?
 self.shapeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer(
```

Comment: Use `myView.removeFromSuperview()` in case your lines are represented by a custom `UIView` subclass.

Comment: How did you draw the lines?

Comment: You can clear without remove from superView `myImageView.image = nil`

Comment: The best way to clear UIImageView have ishidden property set it to true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one good option could be to do `myImageView.image = nil`, so you could re assign an image to your imageView after that, without having to add it again to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Try with below

```
imageView.removeFromSuperview()
```

OR

```
imageView.ishidden = true
```